# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'STORES' to data type int.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, stored-procedures, asmx

I am executing a stored procedure in a C# asmx webservice.
the stored procedure is as follows:

```
@userName NVARCHAR(50),
@password NVARCHAR(50),
@defaultTabApp NVARCHAR(20) OUT
AS
Declare @defaultTabApptemp NVARCHAR(20)
set @defaultTabApptemp ='NoAccess'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    if EXISTS(SELECT Top 1  [userId],[userName] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [userName]=@userName AND [password]=@password AND [AppAccess]=N'Yes') 
    Begin
       set @defaultTabApptemp = (select Top 1 [dbo].[users].[defaultTabApp] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [userName]=@userName AND [password]=@password AND [AppAccess]=N'Yes')
    end
 select @defaultTabApp =  @defaultTabApptemp 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
return @defaultTabApp
```

my c# code is:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string Login(string userName, string userPass)
        {
            string result;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(new DBConnection().ConnectionString);
           
            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("_getSpecificUserLogin", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                
                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", userPass);
               

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@defaultTabApp", SqlDbType.NVarChar,20);
                cmd.Parameters["@defaultTabApp"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@defaultTabApp"].Value);

            }


            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
}
```

i'm getting the exception found in the title on this line:`int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` I tried to change it to executescalar but had the same problem. I have no int types in my stored procedure. what is the problem exactly? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your procedure seems a little confused. Have you run the procedure using SSMS and examined its output is correct? I don't believe you have the correct syntax, or can use the RETURN statement for the purpose you are intending. Please supply the table schema and sample data.

Comment: And there is no need for `if exists...select...` you can do it all in one line, and then you don't need a transaction either I hope you are not storing plaintext passwords...

Comment: actually my co-worker wrote the stored procedure and I am supposed to write the c# code of the webservice. so the best thing to do is not use the return statement?

Answer (score 1):

The bare bones of your login procedure should look something like the following.

Note, you do not need a transaction, nor do you need to check if anything exists first - that's implied by the fact it assigns a value to your output variable.

Your code doesn't handle the case where the password is incorrect, or if there are no enabled apps for the user.

In reality, you would validate the user first and assign them some sort of ticket to indicate they have logged in successfully and would not be repeatedly checking their password; when it comes time to get their default app, they are already authenticated.

You only need a top 1 if you can have a single user with more than one appAccess='Yes', in which case you are missing the ordering criteria by which it will select the correct one - without a specific order clause, the value is essentially random.

The correct syntax for an output parameter is `Output`

I would also hope that if this is a public facing application that the password is not plain text and is stored in the database as a hash of the user's password.

```
create procedure UserLogin
@userName nvarchar(50),
@password nvarchar(50), -- This should be a HASH of the user's password, performed by the application
@defaultTabApp nvarchar(20) output
as
set nocount on
set @defaultTabApp='Default failure message'

select top 1 @defaultTabApp=defaultTabApp
from dbo.Users
where AppAccess=N'Yes'
    and Username=@userName and [Password]=@password 
order by <<criteria if there are more than 1 matching rows>>
Go
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir. the thing is that the webservice will be used for an android app that has a tab layout. each tab corresponds to a department. and so does each user. what we want is that when the user enters his credentials, the username and the password will be the inputs of the webservice method that will call the stored procedure. if the username and password are correct and the user has access to the app, his corresponding let's say department should be returned by the procedure so that in my app I will direct him to the corresponding tab after being logged in.

Comment: sorry for the long comment, I wanted to clarify what the webservice and stored procedure are intended for so I could benefit from what you suggested

Comment: You haven't clarified but I would just stress the importance of not sending passwords between application, webservice and database; the database should not store passwords - either encrypted or unencrypted. Passwords should always be hashed by the application before being sent or used anywhere, and only the hashed value, preferably salted, should be stored. Your password is correct if its hash matches the stored hash. That way, you won't be starring in the next global media announcement when your database gets hacked and all your passwords stolen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN` can only return int. You already used an `OUT` parameter, you should remove `return @defaultTabApp` statement at the end of your stored procedure.

Comment: thanks sir. I removed the return statement as you suggested and it worked. just to understand one thing, if an out parameter is used, there should be no return. so if I want a value from the stored procedure, the return statement is not the way to do that

Comment: Not exactly, you can have output parameter(s) and a return value; they are handled differently by the calling app/function/proc. A return value can only return an integer and is generally used to indicate success or failure, an output parameter can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Declare @defaultTabApptemp NVARCHAR(20)
set @defaultTabApptemp ='NoAccess'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    if EXISTS(SELECT Top 1  [userId],[userName] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [userName]=@userName AND [password]=@password AND [AppAccess]=N'Yes') 
    Begin
       set @defaultTabApptemp = (select Top 1 [dbo].[users].[defaultTabApp] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [userName]=@userName AND [password]=@password AND [AppAccess]=N'Yes')
    end
 select @defaultTabApp =  @defaultTabApptemp 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
return @defaultTabApp
```

with

```
Declare @defaultTabApptemp NVARCHAR(20)

 select Top 1  @defaultTabApptemp=[dbo].[users].[defaultTabApp] FROM [dbo].[users] 
WHERE [userName]=@userName AND [password]=@password AND [AppAccess]=N'Yes')
 if @defaultTabApptemp is null  SET @defaultTabApptemp ='NoAccess'
set @defaultTabApp =  @defaultTabApptemp
```